# Symlink and the PATH variable

Tags: shell-script, symlink, path

I tried to install drush with composer from a script that is runing with `sudo`

```
$nameofuser `logname`
#drush installation
getcomposer(){
# Composer Global installation
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php > /dev/null 2>&1
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer > /dev/null 2>&1
sed -i '1i export PATH="/home/"$nameofuser"/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' /home/"$nameofuser"/.bashrc > /dev/null 2>&1
source /home/"$nameofuser"/.bashrc
}
getdrush(){
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ -f /usr/bin/drush ]; then
rm "/usr/bin/drush"
ln -s  /home/"$nameofuser"/.comoser/vendor/drush/drush/drush /bin/drush
else
ln -s  /home/"$nameofuser"/.comoser/vendor/drush/drush/drush /bin/drsuh
fi  
}
getcomposer
getdrush
```

The restult is

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root Dec 28 14:55 drush --> /home/user/.comoser/vendor/drush/drush/drush
```

drush command is not working instead ubuntu displays

```
 The programm drush ist corrently not installed you can install it by typing: 
 sudo apt-get install drush
```

The result of

`echo $PATH` is

```
/home//.comoser/vendor/bin:/home//.comoser/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local
/bin:/usr/sbin:user/bin:/sbin:/bin:usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

What is wrong here? how to get the $namefuser variable in to the $PATH, correctly,
Why is the symbolic link to drush not working?

Comment: Logname is not defined. Try changing that to your user.

Comment: thats strange because it works for teh rest of the script
but it workjs by replaceing /home/$nameofuser with ~ 
I have to test if this also works when there is already an user on a seted up system

Comment: in your script, you mixed "`.../.composer`" and "`.../.comoser`"

Answer (score 2):

The first line looks wrong.  That should probably be

```
nameofuser=`logname`
```

What you posted doesn't assign anything to nameofuser, and then you try to use it and it evaluates to an empty string.